# Why does express export a function rather than an object at the beginning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When we use express in Node.js, we first use

```
const express = require('express')
```

to import express module, and this will return a function.

Then we use

```
const app = express()
```

Here's my question:

1. What does this `express()` return?

   Because we can use methods like `app.get()` or `app.delete()`. I thought that `express()` probably returns an object
2. If `express()` returns an object, why didn't express just export a object when we `const express = require('express')` at the beginning than export a function?

Comment: It's a factory function which means that by calling it, you generate a new object as you mentioned. That way, you can generate multiple apps / express instances and not only have one global one (If that one were exported by the express package). I guess you could compare it to a class where you would do `const app = new Express()` without the class boilerplate. Hope this makes sense :3

Answer (score 1):

This is what it gets exported: [express.js on GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/06d11755c99fe4c1cddf8b889a687448b568472d/lib/express.js#L37)

It exports a so-called **factory function**: a function that each time it gets called it creates you a new `app` (express application). This allows you to create more than one (isolated) application instance.

The factory function itself returns you another `function` that has its own methods and properties (as legal according to js).

```
function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  app.init();
  return app;
}
```